# how to upper/lower case resx bindings in xaml in xamarin.forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, resx

Following [xamarin localization topic](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/advanced/localization/) and sample [TodoLocalized](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/TodoLocalized), I made my app multilingual. my problem is sometimes, I need to use sometimes words capitalized and I dont want to create another translation in resx files as upper case version of same word. what is the best way to achieve this? if possible to extend this translateextension? or should I use IValueConvertor? if yes how to bind it in xaml

```
    // You exclude the 'Extension' suffix when using in Xaml markup
        [ContentProperty("Text")]
        public class TranslateExtension : IMarkupExtension
        {
            readonly CultureInfo ci;
            const string ResourceId = "myApp.Resx.AppRes";

            public TranslateExtension()
            {
                if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.iOS || Device.OS == TargetPlatform.Android)
                {
                    ci = DependencyService.Get<ILocalize>().GetCurrentCultureInfo();
                }
            }

            public string Text { get; set; }

            public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
            {
                if (Text == null)
                    return "";

                ResourceManager resmgr = new ResourceManager(ResourceId
                                    , typeof(TranslateExtension).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);

                var translation = resmgr.GetString(Text, ci);

                if (translation == null)
                {
#if DEBUG
                    throw new ArgumentException(
                        String.Format("Key '{0}' was not found in resources '{1}' for culture '{2}'.", Text, ResourceId, ci.Name),
                        "Text");
#else
                translation = Text; // HACK: returns the key, which GETS DISPLAYED TO THE USER
#endif
                }
                return translation;
            }
        }
```

my Xaml:

```
     <Button  Image="ic_add.png"   Text="{resx:Translate AddNew}"
 Command="{Binding AddNew}"   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
```

I tried doing this, but I guess Binding expects a property defined in the BindingContext. therefore it doesnt work but how do I achieve it for a text defined in resx file.

```
Text="{Binding {resx:Translate AddNew}, Converter={StaticResource UpperCaseConverter}}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from hankide is also correct however I figured out better solution here. Apparently any public property defined in IMarkupExtension inherited class can be bindable. Referring to sample in the [xamarin doc](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.IMarkupExtension/)

So i just extended my TranslationExtension class with

```
public bool IsUpper { get; set; } = false;
```

and binded that simply where ever I need to be uppercase. I hope this helps any one who is looking for same solution.

```
  <Button  Image="ic_add.png"   Text="{resx:Translate AddNew}"
 Command="{Binding AddNew, IsUpper=true}"   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

You could try something like this:

```
<Button Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource UpperCaseConverter}, ConverterParameter={resx:Translate AddNew}}"/>
```

That way you should be able to access the translated string in the converter

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
     return parameter.ToString().ToUpper();
}
```

If the `ConverterParameter` doesn't work, you could just use the key and get the translated resource inside the converter.

Answer (score 0):

To make this more customizable, you can add a property StringCase in your TranslationExtension as like:

```
[ContentProperty("Text")]
public class TranslateExtension : IMarkupExtension
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string StringCase { get; set; }

    ........
    ........

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(StringCase))
        {
            if (StringCase.ToUpper().Equals("UPPER"))
            {
                translation = translation.ToUpper();
            }
            else if (StringCase.ToUpper().Equals("LOWER"))
            {
                translation = translation.ToLower();
            }
        }
        return translation;
    }
}
```

To keep text normal:

```
<Label Text="{resx:Translate AddNew}"/>
<Button Text="{resx:Translate AddNew}"/>
```

To make it Upper Case:

```
<Label Text="{resx:Translate AddNew, StringCase=Upper}"/>
<Button Text="{resx:Translate AddNew, StringCase=Upper}"/>
```

To make it Lower Case:

```
<Label Text="{resx:Translate AddNew, StringCase=Lower}"/>
<Button Text="{resx:Translate AddNew, StringCase=Lower}"/>
```

This way, you can also add conditions if you want to convert it to CamelCase, PascalCase, SnakeCase or KebabCase (However you may not encounter in cases where you need to convert except Uppercase or Lowercase).